# Safari returns lmvworker 404 error when loading viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am getting the following error when loading the viewer on Safari browsers, both mobile and desktop:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  https://buildreadyapp.com/viewers/blob:https://buildreadyapp.com/lmvworker.min.js.map"
(buildreadyapp is my domain. The viewer file itself is at buildreadyapp.com/viewers/qr_viewer.php)

The error does not show on other browsers. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I believe this issue got resolved when I upped the memory limit for the viewer. [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750203/when-to-load-custom-panorama-extension/55751335#55751335) is related to the same problem. Before I increased the limit, the viewer would get stuck in an infinite 404 error loop and would not load. Now it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Please note it's against the usage license to host Autodesk Forge Viewer.js library on your own service or make any modifications to the code for that matter:

> /*!  * LMV v6.5.4  *   * Copyright 2019 Autodesk, Inc.  * All rights
>   reserved.  *   * This computer source code and related instructions
>   and comments are the  * unpublished confidential and proprietary
>   information of Autodesk, Inc.  * and are protected under Federal
>   copyright and state trade secret law.  * They may not be disclosed to,
>   copied or used by any third party without  * the prior written consent
>   of Autodesk, Inc.  *   * Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:  *
>   * The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by  * Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript
>   must be  * delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.  */

Apart from the license violations you will run into all kinds of dependency issues as lots of the resources are resolved dynamically at our service's end based on requirements of the model files and functionality called for in your code.

Please reference the library via our CDN:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not hosting it on my own server. My code references the CDN. That's why I'm confused about this error. When I mentioned my viewer file I meant my PHP page that calls the viewer

Comment: What version is your Viewer? Nonetheless the error is about not being able to load the [source map](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) which is dispensable in production. Is there any observable issue with functionality though?

Comment: I have the same problem. The viewer tries to send a GET request to my backend requesting '/lmvworker.js.map'. The problem is browser independent. Is there a solution? Memory increase (up to 8GB) does not solve the issue.